# check only one checkbox from treeview

Tags: jquery, treeview

```
$("#grouptree").treeview({
            animated: "fast",
        collapsed: true,
        unique: true,
        persist: "cookie",
        toggle: function() {
            window.console && console.log("%o was toggled", this);
        }
    });
```

above code is my treeview code , 
 Each one checkbox has class='treecheck'  , allow user to check only one checkbox from treeview

Comment: what do you mean by i want to select only one??

Comment: from the treeview allow to check only one checkbox

Answer (score 1):

you have to write change event on class `treecheck` and whenever one is changed uncheck other with this class name.

You can do this way using `not()`:

## HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="treecheck"/>
<input type="checkbox" class="treecheck"/>
<input type="checkbox" class="treecheck"/>
<input type="checkbox" class="treecheck"/>
<input type="checkbox" class="treecheck"/>
```

## JQUERY:

```
$('.treecheck').on('change', function() {
    $('.treecheck').not(this).prop('checked', false);  
});
```

## FIDDLE

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/ehsansajjad465/qXwSX/)